# jQuery ignore hide but accept remove on selector 'option'

Tags: jquery

I'm a bit confused, why I can use `.remove()` but not `.hide()` on an option.
Does someone know why?

The HTML Code:

```
<select>
    <option value="choose">---</option>
    <option value="foo">foo</option>
    <option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>
```

And the Javascript Code:

```
$('select').focus(function() {
    $('option[value="choose"]').hide();
    //$('option[value="choose"]').remove();
});
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PzaHy/10/

Comment: works for me, only problem is that it stil has the first one selected (and you haven't set jQuery as framework in you jsFiddle)

Comment: Both work for me in Chrome 17. What browser are you using?  Also, you saved the jsfiddle against mootools instead of jQuery. Are you trying this in an application, or just jsfiddle?

Comment: yeah i did a new one and just forgot it to select it i updated it.

Comment: same in chrome safari and firefox here... remove() is accepted after focusing but hide not :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select boxes are operating system controls not true HTML rendered elements, so they often do not behave as normal HTML elements would.

Comment: seems like its not possible to hide it :/ i removed it

Answer (score 1):

It will not work. If you don't want to remove you can disable them. Try this

```
$('select').focus(function() {
    $('option[value="choose"]').attr('disabled', true);
});
```